# Java Higher or lower Grid Game

Tags: java, user-interface, grid, numbers

How do create a popup that takes a random number between 0 and 19 after the user clicks on a numbered button to tell them if the answer is correct, the number is higher, or lower?

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GridGame implements ActionListener {
JFrame main;
int rows = 4;
int cols = 4;
JButton button; 
int winningNum;

public GridGame()  {
    main = new JFrame();
    main.setContentPane(makePanelGrid());
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE static refrence
    main.pack();
    main.setVisible(true);
}

public JPanel makePanelGrid(){
    JPanel grid = new JPanel();
    grid.setLayout(new GridLayout(rows,cols,10,10));

    for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
        grid.add(new JButton(i+""));
        winningNum= (int) (Math.random() * 19);
    }
    return grid;
}

public static void main(String[] Args){
    new GridGame();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == button){
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. Also, what does your current code have to do with the question? What have you tried regarding the popup?

Comment: i couldnt figure out how to format the code properly. Right now the code is set up to build the grid of button. How do create a popup saying the number is correct, higher, or lower when the user clicks on a button.

Answer (score 1):

From the question you asked it seems as if you want to take an input from a pop up box? If so you could use [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)'s [showInputDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.lang.Object)) method. It is pretty easy to use and here is an example specific to what you want to do.

The only thing you need to do is define an int to store the results of this method.

```
public int showDialog()
{
    int guess = 0;

    try{ 
        guess = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a number between 0 and 19"));
    }catch(Exception ex){
        showDialog();
    }

    if(guess < 0 || guess > 19 )
        showDialog();

    return guess;
}
```

So, you can do something like `int answer = showDialog();`.

If you just want to show a message in a pop up box then you could use the [showMessageDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)) method.

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "My message.");`

That should work for displaying if the guess is too high or low etc. You could also just put it in a method like:

```
public void showMessageDialog(String message)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message); 
}
```

So that you can pass it the message that you want to display.

I hope this helps.